# How to change the location of user's download folder?

Tags: macos, folders

I want to change the path for a download folder that's created as a default download folder on my mac, but I don't know how to do that.

My goal is to have a different path for the default Downloads folder so that all apps can still access it but on a different path. 
Can this be done on a mac?

Comment: It's been my experience that the location to download files to is set at the application level, not the system level. If there is a global setting, for a stand alone user, I'm not aware of it. Typically one sets the download location in the Application's preferences, which by default is the Downloads folder in the User's Home folder..

Comment: Did you try General tab on the Safari preferences?

Answer (score 2):

Delete the old folder and symlink the new download path to the old download path. Make sure to copy everything in the old download directory to the new directory.

Note: This will only work in bash, so make sure to type in `bash` into terminal and ignore any warnings given about bash no longer being used.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# set newdir to the new directory
NEWDIR=/path/to/new/download/path
# This path can also be relative to the user path (~/relative/to/user/path)

# copy all files in old directory to new directory
find "~/Downloads" -type f -exec cp {} "$NEWDIR"/ \;

# move old directory to new directory
cd ~/Downloads
shopt -s dotglob
for item in *
do
    mv $item "$NEWDIR/"
done

# delete folder and contents in the default path
rm -rf ~/Downloads

# symlink new path to old path
ln -s "$NEWDIR"/ ~/Downloads
```

Comment: The `find` _command_, as currently written, only copies _files_ not any _folders_ that may, and often do, exist in `~/Downloads`, so one looses any hierarchical folder structure that may exist. It also has the potential to overwrite _files_ without warning by not copying _directories_ as well, if they exist. By default one cannot delete the `~/Downloads` _directory_ as its **Access Control Lists** is set to `group:everyone deny delete`, so this _script_ fails when run in at least the last few releases of **macOS**!

Comment: should add a `chmod -h 700 ~/Downloads` to make the symlink's permissions equal to the old Downloads folder (fixes issues with airdrop)

Comment: 1. Absolutely no need for the `find` _command_ or the `for` _loop_ as e.g., `cp -R ~/Downloads/* '/path/to/destination/'` does it! -- 2. By default one cannot delete the `~/Downloads` _directory_ as its **Access Control Lists** is set to `group:everyone deny delete`, so this script fails when run in every default install of **macOS** since at least 10.8.